# React useRef Hook with Flow Typings

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, web-component, flowtype

I'm using React useRef with Flow typings and I'm trying to write a wrapper component for a third party web components library.

The web component expects a changeCallback function and I'm using the ref to assign it to the ref.

```
function RadioButtonGroup({ onChange, children }) {
    const ref: { current: null | ElementRef<ElementType> = React.useRef(null);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        if (ref.current) ref.current.changeCallback = onChange;
    }, [onChange]);

    return <web-component ref={ref}>{children}</web-component>
}
```

Since HTMLElement does not contain a property called changeCallback flow throws an error.

> Cannot assign `handleChange` to `ref.current.changeCallback` because property `changeCallback` is missing in  `HTMLElement`

I tried extending "ElementType" with the property like this

```
ElementRef<ElementType & { changeCallback: Function }>
```

But this results in the following error:

> Cannot instantiate `ElementRef` because  object type [1] is not a React component.

The web component does not fire the "change" event on change. It executes the function changeCallback. Here's the documentation for the library.

```
// MyComponent.js

class MyComponent extends Component {

    constructor() {
        // ...

        // Create a ref
        this.sdxSelectEl = React.createRef();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // Attach callback here to ref
        this.sdxSelectEl.selectCallback = (selection) => console.log(selection);
    }

    render() {
        // ...
        <sdx-select ref={el => (this.sdxSelectEl = el)} />
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is to call useRef with an explicit type argument to represent the expected type:

```
const ref = React.useRef<null | (HTMLElement & { changeCallback: Function })>(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use `addEventListener` to attach the callback to a web component:

```
if (ref.current) ref.current.addEventListener('change', onChange);
```

Comment: That does not work because the web-component does not use the change event for handling changes. It executes a function called changeCallback on change

Comment: @TimoJokinen Can you add the code or any documentation of the web component to your question?

Comment: I updated my question with the libraries documentation. Unfortunately the library is not public and this is all of the documentation for react. When I disable flow my code works btw, it's just about the typings.